# @Html.ActionLink submetendo formulário Post MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, post

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MinhaAction", "MeuController", FormMethod.Post ))
{
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Empresa</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Situação</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="@Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController", item)">@item.Empresa</a></td>
                        <td><a href="@Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController", item)">@item.Cliente</a></td>
                        <td><a href="@Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController", item)">@item.Situacao</a></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

É possivel submeter um formulário dessa forma? Qual a solução pra essa questão?

Comment: Não entendi. Qual o problema enfrentado?

Comment: A minha intenção era de que o usuário clicando em qualquer dado da célula desta tabela o sistema teria que guardar esse objeto e passar pra minha View via Post sem que pra isso eu adicione um botão(com submit) nessa tabela.

Answer (score 1):

Não. Há um confusão feroz de conceitos aí.

Um formulário `POST` envia informações de um formulário usando o protocolo de submissão de dados. Clicar em um link é uma requisição `GET` que envia informações através do endereço HTTP requisitado.

O que você quer fazer, provavelmente, é tipificar alguma informação a ser enviada. Isto pode ser feito usando algum componente de informação, como um `radiogroup` ([`@Html.RadioButton()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) ou então [`@Html.RadioButtonFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobutton(v=vs.118).aspx)) e tratando o campo na *Action*.

Não esqueça de colocar o botão de `submit`:

```
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
```